# Syntax Highlight Problem for Latex/Tikz

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, filetype-tex, syntax

I have a tikzpicture inside a latex file. My problem is that when I open the file and jump with `GG` to the end of the file, the math environment inside the tikz-nodes is  not highlighted (e.g. `$v_0^1$`). The dollar signs as well as the stuff inside it is 'white'.
However, when I scroll (pressing `j`) from the start to the bottom, it highlights the math stuff correctly (dollar signs as well as the math content). I have no clue why this happens.

I tried to create a minimal working example, and I really need the spaced lines + singleton lines to have the bug, otherwise it works correctly. Some things which might be interesstring to know: Removing the \section-command does fix the problem. My file has 144 lines, When I press `GG`, the topmost line I still see is line 113. I run Arch Linux and vim version 'version 8.2.1704'. My .vimrc is

```
syntax enable
let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'
```

The file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\begin{document}
w






























\section{test}
test
test

























w



e

w

w


w
w


w

w
w
w
w




w
w

w
w

w
w

w







    \begin{figure}[t]
      
      







      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[ above left = 8ex and 8ex of v1] (v01) {$v_0^1$};
        \node[ below left = 8ex and 8ex of v1] (v02) {$v_0^\PVCParal$};
        \node[below left = 1ex and 2ex of v02] (labelV0) {\Large$V_0(\GK)$};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
























\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This happens with any kind of file with complex syntax (and even sometimes with simple syntax). Does `:syntax sync fromstart` help?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you! Can you please link me to some resource on why and when this happens? I'm really interested in why this only happens for this one tikz-picture, but not for my other ones.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure; I think it has to do with vim's syntax not "catching up," particularly with recursive syntaxes. cf. `:help :syn-sync`

Comment: Thank you for the reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't suggest *why* this happens (cf. `:help :syn-sync`), a usual fix is `:syntax sync fromstart`, or to increase `maxlines`, or similar tweaks.